# jQuery toggleClass to rotate 180° doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an image ( img tag ) rotate 180° when it's clicked.

```js
$(document).off('click', '.taxonomie').on('click', '.taxonomie', function (e) {
    $(".chevron-occasion").toggleClass("flip");
});
```

```css
.mon-plateau-de-fromages .form-plateau-fromage .chevron-occasion {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 b-gold taxonomie occasion">
   <p class="number-left">1</p>
   <div>
     <p class="titre-taxonomie">Par occasion</p>
     <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/chevron.png" alt="chevron occasion" class="chevron-occasion">
   </div>
   <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/calendar.png" alt="calendar occasion" class="img-occasion">
</div>
```

So at first the "flip" class was added and removed on click. Then I removed the argument " e " in the function, just in case a miracle would make it work, but it didn't.

The image I need to rotate is the first, called "chevron-occasion", why doesn't it work ?

Thanks !

Comment: share a full code including the order, we need to see where you are adding the jQuery code, before or after. We need to also see the generated HTML not PHP

Comment: if you want us to help you need to provide full working code where we can see the issue. If you will try things blindly on your side until something works, no need to accept the first answer, you may in this case remove the question. We need to provide accurate explanation based on real issues

Comment: Just replacing the PHP code that you show for the image URL with a valid image URL results in this code working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly. Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/924105/

try this css

```
.flip {
  animation: animate 4s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg)
  }
}
```

Also in your above code the argument 'e' does not have any functionality. So, removing the argument won't have any effect.